# Pre-populate JQuery date picker in Apex

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Page:

```
<apex:input value="{!startDate}" label="Start Date" id="date1"/>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
        $.datepicker.regional['en-GB']
    );
    $(function() {
        $( "[id$=date1]" ).datepicker();
        $( "[id$=date2]" ).datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public Date startDate {get;set;}   
public AttendanceView_AdvancedInputCont(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        startDate = Date.newInstance(2016,8,31);
    }
```

I have tried to default the date in the constructor, however this doesn't format properly. (See below.) If I select a date it appears as 19/04/2016 as it should.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be changing your `startDate` property to String instead of Date and later parsing it back to Date.

For example:

```
 public String startDate {get;set;}   
 public AttendanceView_AdvancedInputCont(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        Date orginalDate = Date.newInstance(2016,8,31);
        startDate = orginalDate.format();
        }
```

Later, on setting new value from the page, you can change the string type to Date by

```
Date dateValue = Date.parse(startDate);
```